# Is "can be viewed using many different devices" correct? Is it missing a word?

Tags: grammaticality, verbs, understanding

> Web pages can be **viewed using** many different devices: desktops, tablets, and phones.

I don't understand "viewed using" section. I think it miss a certain word.

Comment: You could optionally add the preposition "by": "Web pages can be viewed **by** using many different devices..."

Answer (score 2):

> Web pages can be viewed.

How can they be viewed?

> They can be viewed ***using many different devices***.

Many different devices may be used to view web pages.

Comment: I think it must add the preposition "by" (as @BillJ said above). They can be viewed **by** using many different devices.

Comment: @PhamVanDuc BillJ also says that the *by* is **optional**.

Comment: The full passive sentence is _They can be viewed **by** using many different devices._ . and the reduced the sentence is : _They can be viewed using many different devices._ (reduce "by").  Is that right?

Comment: To this US English speaker, the version with "by" sounds weird, and I'm not sure the original sentence is a reduced version of it.  It's perfectly normal and fluent as it is.

Comment: is there any difference between two sentences?